# Binary operation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I Have an array which looks like this,

```
array([[[-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    ..., 
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024]],

   [[-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    ..., 
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024]],

   [[-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    ..., 
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024]],

   ..., 
   [[-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
    [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
```

Its a lengthy array with many unique elements, how do i do an operation where if the value is greater than 100 make the value 1 else make all values 0.

I tried

```
resulted  = np.array([0 if x < 100 else 1 for x in new_one])
```

But i get,

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>        in ()
>       ----> 1 resulted  = np.array([0 if x < 100 else 1 for x in new_one])
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-72-77697094b8bd> in <listcomp>(.0)
> ----> 1 resulted  = np.array([0 if x < 100 else 1 for x in new_one])
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is        ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
> ```

Any ideas on how i can take this forward?Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried `for list in array: for number in list, if number <100: number =0 else: number =1 didnt work though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Astype int of boolean will give you want you want i.e

```
arr = np.array([[[-1024, -1024, -1024, 0, -1024, -1024, -1024],
[-1024, -1024, -1024, 150, -1024, -1024, -1024],
[-1024, -1024, -1024,300, -1024, -1024, -1024]]])


(arr>100).astype(int)

array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: I just had one more question,If i wanted to set all the elements which are -1024 to 0,how would i go about doing that,any suggestions?

Comment: Ryan then `(arr!=-1024).astype(int)` would help

Comment: Thanks Dark, but this one turns everything else into 1,what i had in mind was convert -1024 to 0 and leave everythinhg else in the array as it is,any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan you are looking for where i.e `np.where(arr!=-1024,arr,0)`

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can comparison operators directly on the numpy arrays:

```
new_one >= 100
```

This will construct an array with the same shape as the `new_one`, except that it is filled with booleans that are `True` in case the corresponding element of `new_one` is greater than or equal to `100`, and vice versa.

Since `True` acts as 1 and `False` acts as `0`, this should be sufficient. In case you really want integers, you can use:

```
(new_one >= 100).astype(int)
```